# ¿Cómo difuminar el borde de Clip-path, en un enmascaramiento?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

**Busco difuminar los bordes de una mascara, ejemplo:**

1)sin difuminar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Con borde difuminado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente hacerlo con box-shadow/css pero no lo conseguí, Si se puede hacer con css excelente; pero si es con javascript, genial!... Cualquier sugerencia seria de mucha ayuda. gracias!!!

**NOTA:** las imágenes de fondo son aleatorias, si no nota la diferencia de los fondos, solo vuelva a ejecutar.

```js
let img1 = document.querySelector(".img1");
let box = document.querySelector(".box");
const t = img1.getBoundingClientRect();
function moverCursor(e){
    let m = e.pageX - t.left  ;
    let n = e.pageY - t.top  ;
    img1.style.setProperty(`--x`,`${m}px`);
    img1.style.setProperty(`--y`,`${n}px`);
}
box.addEventListener("mousemove", moverCursor);
```

```css
.box {
   width: 500px;
   height: 250px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   position: relative;
   background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/250);
}

.img1 {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/500/250); 
   --x: 0px;
   --y: 0px;
   --r: 80px;
   clip-path: circle(var(--r) at var(--x) var(--y));
}
```

```html
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img1"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: onda `opacity: .5;` en el img1?

Comment: ```opacity: .5;``` solo hace que el fondo se vea parcialmente. lo que intento es difuminar los bordes.

Comment: mepa q va mas por el lado de svg mask, el clip path de css puede que no tome un gradient fill ( igualmente verifica que la composición del ejemplo no esté usando un blend overlay/multiply aprovechando el background negro de ambas layers )

Comment: btw hay un css para usar [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) pero el compatibility list lo veo muy escaso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando un `SVG` con [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) y [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter) podes lograr algo muy parecido.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let box = document.querySelector(".box");
let img1 = document.querySelector(".img1");
const t = img1.getBoundingClientRect();
let bg = img1.querySelector('image');

function moverCursor(e) {
  let x = e.pageX - t.left - (t.width / 2);
  let y = e.pageY - t.top - (t.height / 2);
  
  img1.style.setProperty(`top`, `${y}px`);
  img1.style.setProperty(`left`, `${x}px`);
  
  bg.style.setProperty(`x`, `${-x}px`);
  bg.style.setProperty(`y`, `${-y}px`);
}
box.addEventListener("mousemove", moverCursor);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/250);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg class="img1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="150" height="150">
    <defs>
      <filter id="filter">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
      </filter>
      <mask id="mask">
        <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="40%" ry="40%" fill="white" filter="url(#filter)"></ellipse>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/500/250" width="500" height="250" mask="url(#mask)"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```